# Query with join 20 times slower than queries in a loop with php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to make some optimizations in queries of my site. I've allways thought that, it is better to use one query with a "JOIN" than put severals queries in a php loop, but when I do it, it is really slow.

The original method with queries in loop takes 0.055s and the new with "join" takes 1.084s.. Wich solution should I use ? And is there a way to make the new query faster ? Maybe another idea is to create a procedure in mysql with loop ?

Here is the situation : I've a forum, with topics in forum, and messages in topics. And to get the username, I get the id of the user in the msgs table and if this is positive it is a registered user else it's a guest in the guests table. Don't know if this is a good construction, but I can't put guest and registered member in the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE `topic` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_date` int(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_answere_date` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `author_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `msgs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` int(14) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `guests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And My two situations :

```
//Goal : get the list of 5 new topics or topic with new messages
//Methode query in loop
    $timestart=microtime(true);
    echo '<h3>Query in loop</h3>';
    //Get the list of new topics
    $reqTopic = $bdd->query('SELECT id,title,author_name,post_date FROM topic ORDER BY last_answere_date DESC LIMIT 0,5');
    While($topic = $reqTopic->fetch())
    {
        //Get the last message
            $reqMsgs = $bdd->prepare('SELECT count(*) as msgCount, user_id,post_date FROM msgs WHERE topic_id=? ORDER BY post_date DESC');
            $reqMsgs->bindparam(1,$topic['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $reqMsgs->execute();
            $msg = $reqMsgs->fetch();
        //IF the id is >0 then it's a registered member, else it's a guest
            if($msg['user_id'] > 0)
                $reqAuthor = $bdd->prepare('SELECT nom as name FROM users WHERE id=? LIMIT 0,1');
            else
                $reqAuthor = $bdd->prepare('SELECT name FROM guests WHERE id=? LIMIT 0,1');

            $reqAuthor->bindparam(1,$msg['user_id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $reqAuthor->execute();
            $author = $reqAuthor->fetch();
        //Output
        echo '<strong>'.$topic['title']. '</strong><br/>'
            .'Author : '. $topic['author_name'] . ' | Date : '. date('d/m/Y H:i',$topic['post_date']) .'<br/>';
            if($msg['msgCount'] > 0)
            {
                echo 'Last msg author : '. $author['name'] . ' | Date : '. date('d/m/Y  H:i',$msg['post_date']) .'<br/>'
                .'Nbr msgs : '.$msg['msgCount'].'<br/>';
            }
            echo '<br/>';

    }
    //End of script : get time
    $timeend=microtime(true);
    $time=$timeend-$timestart;
    echo '<strong>'.number_format($time, 10) . ' sec</strong>';

//Methode Left join
    $timestart=microtime(true);
    echo '<h3>Left Join</h3>';
    //The query
        $reqTopic = $bdd->query('SELECT t.id,title,t.author_name,t.post_date, m.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM msgs WHERE t.id=topic_id) as msgCount
        FROM topic t
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT m.id,topic_id,post_date as mdate,user_id, IFNULL(u.nom,i.name) as name
            FROM msgs m
            LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=m.user_id
            LEFT JOIN guests i ON i.id=-m.user_id
            GROUP BY topic_id
            ORDER BY post_date DESC
            ) m
            ON t.id=m.topic_id
        GROUP BY t.id
        ORDER BY last_answere_date DESC LIMIT 0,5');
    While($topic = $reqTopic->fetch())
    {

        //Output
        echo '<strong>'.$topic['title']. '</strong><br/>'
            .'Author : '. $topic['author_name'] . ' | Date : '. date('d/m/Y H:i',$topic['post_date']) .'<br/>';
            if($topic['msgCount'] > 0)
            {
                echo 'Last msg author : '. $topic['name'] . ' | Date : '. date('d/m/Y  H:i',$topic['mdate']) .'<br/>'
                .'Nbr msgs : '.$topic['msgCount'].'<br/>';
            }
            echo '<br/>';

    }
    //End of script : get time
    $timeend=microtime(true);
    $time=$timeend-$timestart;
    echo '<strong>'.number_format($time, 10) . ' sec</strong>';
```

Comment: What is your question?  The two pieces of code appear to be doing very different things, which would explain the difference in performance.

Comment: The output is exactly the same for both. I've read many times that this is not good to put queries in php loop, but when I try to not do it, this is extremely slower. So, is there a solution to optimize the second query, or in this case, is the first solution better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the optimal approach for this kind of stuff is to proceed in two steps:

1. Fetch the rows that you need
2. Fetch data related to those rows

In your case, start by fetching your topics:

```
SELECT id,title,author_name,post_date
FROM topic
ORDER BY last_answere_date DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Using the fetched topic ids, then fetch the related data:

```
SELECT topic_id, user_id, post_date
FROM msgs
WHERE topic_id IN (…)
ORDER BY topic_id, post_date DESC

SELECT id, nom as name FROM users WHERE id IN (…)
```

etc.

In your particular case, a correlated subquery can yield the count cheaply, if you really want SQL to return it:

```
SELECT t.id,title,t.author_name,t.post_date,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM msgs WHERE t.id=topic_id) as msgCount
FROM topic t
ORDER BY t.last_answere_date DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

(In the above, the planner should get the rows first, and then run the subquery once per row.)

The problem with using a left join to retrieve everything in one go like you did is that:

1. You may needlessly end up joining enormous sets that can result from using a `group by` statement in a subquery, because the latter can prevent the use of an index;
2. You may lose the benefit of indexes that might kick in when doing `where … order by … limit …` due to order by clauses within subqueries that you join on; and
3. You multiply the times you send the data by the number of related rows — e.g. topic-related data gets sent once *per message* in your left join query. (This is likely negligible in your particular case, but it may add up in others.)

Comment: Indeed, this should be the approach.